# Questions about building android from source

Tags: android, android-source, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-kernel, fastboot

I'm trying to add a kernel module to the android kernel for my Nexus 7 (flo). So I built the kernel and copied the zImage to the following location

```
/source_tree_location/device/asus/flo-kernel/kernel
```

in the android source tree (I am trying to build JB). The kernel image is generated without any issues.

Then I extracted the binaries for the hardware using the scripts provided by Qualcomm, Broadcom, asus. Source build/envsetup.sh, chose the target as aosp_flo_userdebug and built the source tree.This too builds without a problem

Then I flashed the image using fastboot:

```
  fastboot flashall
```

from the root location of the source tree. But my device doesn't boot. It seems to go into a bootloop with it only going till the Google logo

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you use fastboot flashall, do you use fastboot flashall -W to wipe the user data? If you don't, left over user data could stop your device from booting easily. If that's not it, check adb logcat. The kernel can build and still cause your device not to boot. Look for useful messages.

Comment: Thanks I fixed an issue with the kernel and it worked! I have another question. How do I ndownload google apps now? I can't add my google accounts under settings->add account. I can't download the apk and use adb to install it either. In this way the download works, but the app(google play store) crashes.

Comment: The google apps are proprietary and not available for public use. See how cyanogen does it: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps